# Correct Proof Of ZBC Theorem From Odifreddi? Also Extension Question

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, recursively-enumerable

So I'm looking at the proof of the ZBC lemma in Odifreddi's Classical Recursion Theory volume 2 page 808 and I don't see why $ 0' \oplus C$ produced computes $B'$ as claimed.  The positive requirements try and code 
$$
P^C_e: \; x \in C^{[e]} \iff (\exists z > x) B^{[e]}(x) \not=  B^{[e]}(z)
$$

Now if these requirements always succeeded we would be great.  We could read off from $C^{[e]}$ the point at which $B^{[e]}$ achieved its limit and from that compute $W$ which in turn computes $B'$.  However, higher priority negative requirements might restrain $P^C_e$ from acting.  These requirements have the form.
$$
N^C_e : \; (\exists_\infty s)(\phi^{B\oplus C_s}_{e,s}(e)\downarrow) \implies \phi^{B\oplus C}_{e}(e)\downarrow
$$

However, since $B$ isn't low we can't guarantee that $0'$ can tells us whether or not such a higher priority negative requirement might be falsely resulting in $C^{[e]}(x)=0$ so how do we actually conclude that $B' \leq_T 0' \oplus C$?

---

While I'm at it am I correct in presuming that the only reason that one can assume we meet the negative requirement for $B$ is that we assumed $C$ meets its own negative requirements above.  This almost makes me think the right proof would build them simultaneously so they satisfied a requirement more like

$$
N^C_e : \; (\exists_\infty s)(\phi^{B^{e}_s\oplus C_s}_{e,s}(e)\downarrow) \implies \phi^{B\oplus C}_{e}(e)\downarrow
$$

where 
$$B^{e}_s(x) = \begin{cases}
B(x) & \text{ if } x = <i,y> \land i \leq e \\
B_s(x) & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

That way one could get some kind of induction off the ground where $0'$ would be able to determine if the next negative requirement ever engaged using the knowledge  of $B'$ restricted to $e$.  Or is there some easier trick I'm missing?

---

Note that the reason I'm interested is that I wanted to see if I could extend the ZBC theorem so that given r.e. set $A$ and set $W$ r.e. in $A$ it produced $B, C$ with $B \oplus C \leq_T A \oplus W$ and $(B \oplus C)' \equiv_T 0'\oplus B \oplus C \equiv_T 0' \oplus W$.  So thoughts about that are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof of Harrington’s ZBC Lemma can be found in Theorem 2.5 of

*Hinman, Peter G.; Slaman, Theodore A.*, [**Jump embeddings in the Turing degrees**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2274700), J. Symb. Log. 56, No. 2, 563-591 (1991). [ZBL0745.03036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0745.03036).

It [consists](https://math.berkeley.edu/~antonio/papers/GHembpdf.pdf) of a finite injury construction on top of an infinite
injury construction. So it sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks1